# FontFamily "Material Design Icons" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-paper

*** I am just a student and I am new to expo, react-native and mobile developpement ***

So here's what happens

I am building a react-native app using Expo and react-native-paper for my Icon and everything was going fine with my application  until I woke up yesterday and Expo started  telling me the same error.

[image]

I have not load any Font in my app so I really dont understand where this error came from.

What is very interesting is that when I control Save one files of the project  on VScode  while running, I can see my app like this without the Icon, and when I switch  to a different page, the App is replace by the same screen  error.

[image]

My friend is working on the exact same code and he does not see the error so I am lost ...

App.js look like this 
[image]

I use my Icon like this 
[image]

The problem is clearly the icon because my login page work just fine, so I know the problem have somethings with https://materialdesignicons.com/, what should I do ? delete all my icon and recreate them with react-native-elements?

Honestly I just don't get it and I have been stuck on this for several hours and I don't want to lose any more time so here I am asking for help

Thanks guys,

Have a blessed day and stay safe you all

Answer (score 2):

So there is a bug right now using `Expo` with using custom fonts.  Check your `node_modules/expo/node_modules` folder and delete `expo-font` if it is there.  That has been working for me.

Make sure to delete the `expo-font` inside the `node_modules/expo/node_modules` NOT the one in `node_modules`.

I know you said you are not using custom fonts but maybe it is an issue regardless.

Note: if you run `expo install` or `npm install` it will come back so you'll have to delete again.

Comment: Thanks mate, the problem is the IconButton with React-native-paper because when I delete all the IconButton the app start working. I will report my bugs to expo I think

Comment: I’m having same issue in my project but ~ node_modules/expo/node_modules~ does not exist in my project